# Window is undefined error, when loading node_module package in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, color-picker

I am trying to use `pickr` package ( a color picker library) in my `nuxt.js` app , at import time it is providing error called **window is undefined**

here is code:

```
<script>
import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr/dist/pickr.min.js';

let pickr;

export default {
  name: "ColorPicker",
  mounted(){
    pickr = Pickr.create({
          el: '.test-picker',
          theme: 'classic',
          swatches: [
              'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
              'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
          ],
  
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

#### tried approaches

- i made `pickr` package as a nuxt plugin added it to `nuxt.config.js` with `mode:client`
- i made `pickr` package as a nuxt plugin added it to `nuxt.config.js` with `ssr:false`

but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggles i came up with this approach and did work for me

```
<script>

let PickrInstance;

if(process.browser){
   PickrInstance = require('@simonwep/pickr/dist/pickr.min.js')
}

let  pickr;

export default {
  name: "ColorPicker",
  mounted(){
    pickr = PickrInstance.create({
          el: '.test-picker',
          theme: 'classic',
          swatches: [
              'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
              'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
          ],

      });
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap it in the custom Vue component (`VComponent.vue`) and render this component inside [client-only](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component) tag

```
<client-only>
  <v-component />
</client-only>

...

import VComponent from './VComponent';

export default {
  components: { VComponent },
}
```

If it still throws an error, you can try to dynamically load your custom component. Instead of `import VComponent from './VComponent'` use:

```
const VComponent = () => import('./VComponent');
```